Window hard to open even after silicone spray
Fixed: See last update.
A few of my windows are hard to open and close, even after I lubricated everything I could see with silicone spray. (See photo.)
How might I try to get these windows to open and close more easily?

Update:
Based on input on DIY, I looked for a spring system but did not find one. Instead, I saw what seems to be aluminum tubes that are discolored and a little rough when I run my finger over them. (See photos.)
How do I take apart the window enough to get to these tubes so I can sand them down w emory cloth or lubricate them?


Update 2:
The problem was the spiral balances (see photos) were dirty and lost their lubricant.  I cleaned them a little with alcohol on rag and lubricated them with silicone spray and the windows now move much more easily.  If the problem reoccurs, I'll do the same thing but more thoroughly.



I do not see any levers/squeezes to lock that window in position.  I f they only use friction to hold, then being tight is a design feature and not a problem.

@crip659  This design feature has become a problem.  It is harder to open and close than in past years.

A hung sash almost always has a spring or weight/pully system to assist opening/closing and to hold them up in the open and/or closed position. I would bet that you have a spiral sash balance or channel sash balance (both common in vinyl windows) that is either damaged, in need of tensioning, or in need of lubrication (grease). A window that is out-of-square could also be a cause.



I do not see a spring system but when I looked I saw some corroded tubes (see addition to the original question for photo.)

Based on your post, I looked more and there is a spring balance (which I cleaned and lubricated). I updated the question with the solution, including photos.

Good start; in your later photos you can see the actual spiral sash rod(s), exposed below the tubes. These should be greased with white household grease.
